# Degree of a variety is well-defined

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety embedded in a projective space, over a field of arbitrary characteristic.

What is a good reference for a nice proof of the classic fact that degree of $X$ is well-defined, that is, a "general" plane of complementary dimension intersects $X$ in a fixed number of points? (assuming Bertini's theorem). A proof which requires less amount of background is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

See Fulton, "Intersection Theory", Ex. 8.4.12, p. 149.

Answer (score 3):

As Kaveh [says](https://mathoverflow.net/a/103678), the best way is to follow Hartshorne's Chapter I, Section 7. This is before he gets to schemes, so it should be considered "classical".

Thm 7.7 in that section is a slightly generalized version of Bezout's (classical) theorem on the number of points plane curves intersect in. It considers intersections with hypersurfaces.
Now let $X\subseteq \mathbb P^n$ and its degree defined via its Hilbert polynomial (as on page 52). Then by (the proof of)
Bertini's theorem, for a general hyperplane $H\subseteq \mathbb P^n$, $X\cap H$ is reduced and then by Thm. 7.7, $\deg (X\cap H)=\deg X$. Keep cutting with hyperplanes until you get to finitely many points and it is easy to check that the degree of a reduced zero-dimensional scheme is the same as the number of points in it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose one of the best approaches (In my humble view, the best one) to delve into the concept of the degree of a projective variety is the method that has been used in "Algebraic Geometry" by Robin Hartshorne.

More precisely, if you study Chapter 1, Section 7 (Intersections in Projective Space), it will give you a real insight into the matter.
According to the fact that, as it is mentioned in the aforementioned part of the book, a purely algebraic definition of degree has been given, it would be much easier (at least to me) to gain a clear answer to your question.

I would like to mention that Theorem 7.5 (Hilbert–Serre) plays a vital role in the aforesaid section and if you are already familiar with the Hilbert polynomial of a graded module over a polynomial ring and its Hilbert function, you can directly go to Hilbert–Serre Theorem and the rest of the section. Otherwise have a quick look at the whole section and in a few minutes you will get what you want.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (May 12, 2022): While it is probably too late for the purpose of the original posting, but I also wanted a more "direct" way (compared to the approach by Hilbert polynomial) to see degree as the number of points in the intersection with generic linear subspaces with complementary dimension. I could not find a reference, and eventually ended up writing it up myself (see Example III.122 and Theorem III.123 in [Mondal - How many zeroes? Counting the number of solutions of systems of polynomials via geometry at infinity (Draft III)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05346)). It does not use Bertini's theorem, so in positive characteristic needs to count points of intersection with appropriate multiplicities. I am happy to report that while I had forgotten about this question, I actually ended up doing precisely what I suggested 10 years ago, namely following Mumford's proof from "Algebraic Geometry I".

Hi Kiumars, this does not answer your question, since the proof works only when the field is $\mathbb{C}$, but when I was learning it, the most accessible and understandable proof for this case was that of Theorem 5.1 of Mumford's "Algebraic Geometry I: Complex Projective Varieties".

Comment: Since the arXiv does its own automatic counting of versions, what is the significance of putting the draft number in the title of your arXiv submission?

Comment: @LSpice: nothing particular - just a habit to informally refer to articles in arxiv. I agree that your edit is an improvement.